# Clicking hyperlink doesn't work if there is a colon in the link. How can I solve this

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my application , users can post messages, a title and body. The message is then accessed by a user clicking the hyperlink of the title to read the message. However, if a colon is entered by the user the hyperlink is not clickable. I'm looking for the quickest, easiest way of resolving this

The hyperlink is in a GridView so the issue might be related to a colon in the hyperlink, when in a gridview is not clickable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to do [URL encoding](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm) using [`HttpServerUtility.UrlPathEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urlpathencode.aspx)

**Edit**: I'm not sure if I understood correctly whether the colons are in the URL or in the hyperlink text that is clicked?

Comment: I assume from the OP that the problem is colons being rightly interpreted as a port, but yeah it's not super clear. Whatever the problem though encoding is the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the direction, the code worked as:
hlf.DataTextField.Replace(":", Server.UrlEncode(":"));